# How can i know if the user clicked the back button on the previous page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a page that will only redirect the user to a certain page depending on some parameters. So this page will always redirect the visitor.

The problem is when the visitor arrives on this page using the back button. He/She will just be redirected on the page where he/she just clicked the backbutton.

**The context**: Three pages: A, B and C

On page A i click a link to go to page B. page B will simply redirect me to page C.

**The Problem**: Click back on page C. I go to page B for a few seconds but then i'm redirected back to page C

**As it should be**: On Page C, I want to go to page A when i click the back button.

I thought i could use Request.UrlReferrer but this contains the url of page A

Is there any cross browser sollution that will let me do this?

I would prefer a server side sollution, but I'm open for client side too.

EDIT: I just had the idea that it may be possible to replace the entry in the browser history of page B with page A on the moment when the visitor is redirecet to page C. But i don't know if this is possible and allowed.

Comment: a silly solution would be to set a cookie to check where page b is reached from.

Comment: That was my first thought. Write cookie when user reach page C. But if the user is active in different tabs. Or user other navigation on the page and arrives later again on page B, he would not be redirected to the correct page. Or did i misunderstand you?

Comment: the way we did it, add a "back" button to page A and let the back button users do what they want

Comment: Neither did I. Whenever B is reached from from not A redirect to A. Else redirect to B. ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

## History.js

History.js gracefully supports the HTML5 History/State APIs (pushState, replaceState, onPopState) in all browsers. Including continued support for data, titles, replaceState. Supports jQuery, MooTools and Prototype.  For HTML5 browsers this means that you can modify the URL directly, without needing to use hashes anymore. For HTML4 browsers it will revert back to using the old onhashchange functionality.

https://github.com/browserstate/history.js

Comment: I've just tried the demo. Seems good :) I'll see if i can get it to work in my context. I was looking here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history to replaceState() method. But that won't work in all browsers. history.js seems to have a fallback system for non HTML5 supported browsers. Thx